# Наследование и интерфейсы в C++

Tags: c++, ооп, множественное-наследование, виртуальная-функция

Допустим, у меня есть полностью виртуальный/абстрактный класс `INode` (интерфейс), все его методы исключительно виртуальные. В последствии я хочу от него уже наследовать класс `CNode`, где эти методы будут реализованы. Также я хочу создать потомок-интерфейс, например `INodeSpatial`, тоже полностью виртуальный, который унаследует все виртуальные методы родителя + добавит какие-то свои виртуальные методы. В последствии я хочу от него наследовать `CNodeSpatial` где все эти методы будут реализованы. Ну и так далее..

Но тут получается следующее:

1. Класс `CNode`, который наледуется от `INode` будет реализовывать вирутальные методы `INode`
2. Класс `CNodeSpatial`, надедуется, опять же, только от виртуального `INodeSpatial`, но не от `CNode`, и это значит что в `CNodeSpatial` мне придется описывать все то же самое, что было описано в `CNode`
3. Возникла мысль, чтобы этого не делать - наследовать `CNodeSpatial` и от `INodeSpatial`, и от `CNode` (где уже реализация всех виртуальных методов `INode` описана). Тогла мне придется описать только те виртуальные методы, которые есть в `INodeSpatial`

**Но тут возникает вопрос:**

Насколько это вообще хорошо и правильно? Просто получается что класс `CNodeSpatial` дважды наследуется от `INode` (поскольку `INode` является родителем и `CNode` и `INodeSpatial`). Так вообще можно? Не приведет ли это к проблемам в дальнейшем? Насколько такой подход соответствует "хорошей практике"?

**Примеры:**

Интерфейсы

```
class INode
{
public:
    virtual void methodA() = 0;
    virtual void methodB() = 0;
    virtual ~INode() = default;
};

class INodeSpatial : public INode
{
public:
    virtual void methodC(int foo) = 0;
    virtual void methodD(int foo) = 0;
    ~INodeSpatial() override = default;
};
```

"Реальные" классы:

```
class CNode : public INode
{
public:
    void methodA() override
    {
        //TODO: Implementation of INode methods in CNode
    }

    void methodB() override
    {
        //TODO: Implementation of INode methods in CNode
    }
};

class CNodeSpatial : public INodeSpatial
{
public:
    void methodA() override
    {
        //TODO: Implementation of INode methods in CNodeSpatial (already done in CNode)
    }

    void methodB() override
    {
        //TODO: Implementation of INode methods in CNodeSpatial (already done in CNode)
    }

    void methodC([[maybe_unused]] int foo) override
    {
        //TODO: Implementation of INodeSpatial methods
    }

    void methodD([[maybe_unused]] int foo) override
    {
        //TODO: Implementation of INodeSpatial methods
    }
};
```

Как можно видеть, в классе `CNodeSpatial` приходится дублировать реализации которые уже были описаны в `CNode`, потому что наследование идет исключительно от виртуальных интерфейсов. Но если наследоваться И от `СNode`, проблема как бы исчезает:

```
class CNodeSpatial : public INodeSpatial, public CNode
{
public:
    void methodC([[maybe_unused]] int foo) override
    {
        //TODO: Implementation of INodeSpatial methods
    }

    void methodD([[maybe_unused]] int foo) override
    {
        //TODO: Implementation of INodeSpatial methods
    }
};
```

Но в итоге получается то класс как бы 2 раза наследуется от INode, что меня и смущает. Это нормально? Так делают? Проблем в дальнейшем не вызовет?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [KISS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF))

Comment: @AlexNem - а может покажете кодом (виртуальные функции не обязательно писать), как Вы это видите. Может там ничего страшного и нет.

Comment: ¿Почему бы не добавить новые методы в INode и CNode, не создавая никаких новых сущностей?

Comment: @user7860670 Потому что INode/CNode должен отвечать за одно, а INodeSpatial/CNodeSpatial за другое (но при этом сохранять в себе черты и INode/CNode). Это разные сущности с разными задачами. Пихать все-все-все в INode/CNode - по моему убийственно. Интерфейсы использую для того, чтобы можно было в последствии взаимодействовать с объектами из DLL (функции DLL будут возвращать указатели на интерфейсы, а сами интерфейсы - просто заголовочные файлы, подключаемые как на стороне клиента, так и на стороне библиотеки)

Comment: @Alex Nem, Если вам лень кинуть минимальный код(без реализации, с некоторыми членами), то почему кто то должен вместо вас писать пример на догадках ?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan код добавлен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> класс как бы 2 раза наследуется от INode

Чутье вас не подвело.

Ваш пример с `class CNodeSpatial : public INodeSpatial, public CNode` не делает то, что вы думаете.

Класс `CNodeSpatial` при таком подходе абстрактный - попробуйте создать экземпляр, увидите.

Решение - `CNode` и `INodeSpatial` должны наследоваться от `INode` виртуально.

Comment: Действительно, все происходит именно так как вы описали. Создать экземпляры класса не было возможности, покуда не добавил виртуальное наследование. Единственный странный момент - среда (CLion), когда обращаюсь к экземпляру, показывает варианты "spatialNode.CNode::methodA()" и "spatialNode.INode::methodA()", будто есть какая-то неоднозначность. Но скомпилировать с "spatialNode.INode::methodA()" невозможно (ошибка, и понятно почему). Но почему среда показывает этот вариант? Просто баг? Также все работает и собирается если обращаться "spatialNode.methodA()"

Comment: @AlexNem Наверное баг. Не знают, что виртуальное наследование [убирает неоднозначность](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominance_(C%2B%2B))? Стоит зарепортить.

Comment: когда все написано на java/kotlin, то сложно знать о таких "тонких моментах"(хотя какой это тонкий, на каждом нормальном собеседовании спрашивают о ромбовидном/бриллиантовом наследовании). Поэтому я всегда говорю, что не может быть нормальная ide/редактор для с/с++ быть написана не на с/с++.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Еще заметил такую странность, компилятор MSVC почему-то пишет wrning'и (warning C4250: CNodeSpatial: наследуется "CNode::CNode::methodA" через превосходство). При этом MinGW/GCC ничего такого не пишет. Насколько это вообще важно и что имеется в виду? Может все таки что-то не так сделано? CNode и INodeSpatial наследуются виртуально от INode, CNodeSpatial наследуется от CNode обычно, а от INodeSpatial виртуально (но если сделать обычное наследование - ничего не меняется, warning сохраняется)

Comment: @AlexNem Превосходство = dominance, так называется правило про отсутствие неоднозначности в таких случаях. Тут все нормально, просто мелкомягкие считают, что для простых смертных это слишком сложно. :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat понял, спасибо. Кстати, по поводу той странности с CLion (когда он подсказывал 2 варианта), она устраняется если добавлять в класс "using INode::methodA". Тогда он видит только 1 вариант.

Comment: @AlexNem Это интересно, но у них все равно баг.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так:

```
class INodeSpatial : public INode
{
protected:
    virtual void methodC(int foo) {}
    virtual void methodD(int foo) {}
public:
    
    ~INodeSpatial() override = default;
};
```

Так как базовый класс абстрактный, то и производный класс останется абстрактным, поскольку не определяет чистый виртуальный метод. Но он добавляет новые, не чистые, виртуальные методы, но только защищенные, чтобы производные классы могли переопределить и могли не переопределять.
Практически `INodeSpatial` является типичным узловым  классом для построения производных классов:

```
class CNode : public  INodeSpatial
{
public:
    void methodA() override
    {
        
        //TODO: Implementation of INode methods in CNode
    }

    void methodB() override
    {
       
        //TODO: Implementation of INode methods in CNode
    }
};
```

Теперь `CNode` имеет в своем открытом интерфейсе только методы из `INode`

```
class CNodeSpatial : public CNode
{
public:    

    void methodC([[maybe_unused]] int foo) override
    {
       
        //TODO: Implementation of INodeSpatial methods
    }

    void methodD([[maybe_unused]] int foo) override
    {
   
        //TODO: Implementation of INodeSpatial methods
    }
};
```

Ну а этот определил еще и методы из `INodeSpatial`, и имена типов соответствующие иерархии.

Хочется отметить, что я полностью согласен с самым первым комментарием под вопросом(от
avp). Старайтесь делать проще. Например, если нет необходимости создавать дерево иерархии(всего два класса у вас фигурируют в данном виде) так, чтобы было удобно писать рудиментарный код по ссылке на базовый класс, то стоит подумать об избавлении всего лишнего...